# Letters-only regex is including numerals

Tags: regex

I wrote a regex in a function meant to separate capital words by dashes and remove numbers:

```py
def kebabize(string):
    import re
    split_lower_string = [item.lower() for item in re.findall('[a-zA-Z][^A-Z]*', string)]    
    return '-'.join(split_lower_string)
```

Based on my (limited) understanding of regex, the function call on `myCamelHas3Humps` should return `my-camel-has-humps`, based on the `[a-zA-Z][^A-Z]*` expression.

Can someone please walk me through the faulty logic of this regex?

Comment: `[^A-Z]*` means _anything other than `A-Z`_ - including digits :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mathias R. Jessen mentioned in the comments, the problem with your `regex` was *`[^A-Z]*` means anything other than A-Z - including digits*. Your problem can be solved in two steps.

---

### Logic

First we *remove any digits from the input string*. `regex` to find digits is quite simple: `\d`. All the digits need to replaced with empty string.

```
re.sub("\\d", "", input_string)
```

Now, we *find all the positions where we have a lowercase alphabet on the left and uppercase alphabet on the right*. Using positive lookbehind and lookahead we get: `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])`. We need to replace all such positions with `-`.

```
re.sub("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", "-", new_string)
```

---

### Code

```
input_string = "myCamelHas3Humps"
new_string = re.sub("\\d", "", input_string)

string_with_dash = re.sub("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", "-", new_string).lower()
```

There is an extra `lower()` method since you need the final answer in lowercase.

---

### Output

```
my-camel-has-humps
```

Answer (score 0):

`[a-zA-Z][^A-Z]*` will match `a&#%` and `A$.+`.

If you mean to capture only lowercase letters, you should write `[a-zA-Z][a-z]*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude matching digits as well using `[^A-Z\d]*` if you want to "remove numbers"

```
import re
def kebabize(string):
    import re
    split_lower_string = [item.lower() for item in re.findall('[a-zA-Z][^A-Z\d]*', string)]
    return '-'.join(split_lower_string)

print(kebabize("myCamelHas3Humps"))
```

Output

```
my-camel-has-humps
```